# Contact form, magento 1.9 - How to change subject?

Tags: magento-1.9

Does anyone know how to change the email subject when a contact form has been sent? I want to translate it from English "Contact Form" to Swedish "Kontaktformulär". I have tried adding it to app/locale/sv_SE/Mage_Contacts.csv and also into a translate.csv in the theme without success. And I have also searched for it in the form.phtml

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least 2 ways to translate the email subject to another language.

1. Copy `app\locale\en_US\template\email\contact_form.html` into your locale `app\locale\sv_SE\template\email\contact_form.html` and look for the text `<!--@subject Contact Form@-->` and change it to `<!--@subject Kontaktformulär@-->`
2. In backend > System > Transactional Emails > click button "Add New Email Template" > select "Contact Form" in the Template dropdown > click button "Load Template" > change the Template Subject > save it with a new template name.

Comment: I tried the second option first, nothing happened. Then I tried your first option, worked like a charm! :D Thanks a lot!